# how to add datepicker in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

In my grid date field is not displayed when I write the date field in grid. Even grid also not displayed

```
colModel:[
{name:'id',index:'id', width:55, editable:false,editrules:{required:true},searchoptions:{sopt: ['eq', 'ne']}},            
{name:'employe',index:'employe', width:100,editable:true,formoptions:{rowpos:2,elmprefix:"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"},editrules:{required:true}},
{name:'gender',index:'gender', width:55,editable: true, formatter: 'dynamicText', width: 150, edittype: 'custom', editoptions: { custom_element: radioelem, custom_value: radiovalue},formoptions:{rowpos:4,elmprefix:"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"}},
{name:'role',index:'role', width:100,editable:true,edittype:"select",
    editoptions:{dataUrl:'test.txt', defaultValue:'Intime'},
    formoptions:{rowpos:3,elmprefix:"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" }},
{name:'department',index:'department', width:80, align:"right",editable:true,edittype:"select",
    editoptions:{dataUrl:'test.txt', defaultValue:'Intime'},
    formoptions:{rowpos:5,elmprefix:"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" }},
{name:'joinedate',index:'joinedate', width:80,
    editable:true,
    editoptions:{size:12,
        dataInit:function(el){
            $(el).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd '});
        },
        defaultValue: function(){
            var currentTime = new Date();
            var month = parseInt(currentTime.getMonth() + 1);
            month = month <= 9 ? "0"+month : month;
            var day = currentTime.getDate();
            day = day <= 9 ? "0"+day : day;
            var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
            return year+"-"+month + "-"+day;                
        }
    },
    formoptions:{ rowpos:6,elmsuffix:"  yyyy-mm-dd", elmprefix:"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"},
    editrules:{required:true}
}
```

This is my code ..in the grid date field is not displayed please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to put the datepicker-creating method in event:

```
beforeShowForm
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that some versions of jqGrid calls `dataInit` *before* the `el` are placed on the page. So jQuery UI Datepicker don't work in the case. You can fix the problem by calling `datepicker` *later*:

```js
dataInit: function (el) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(el).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd '});
    }, 50);
}
```

Comment: @user2940331: What is not working? I can't verify whether `dateFormat` corresponds the date format which you use. Do you can see datepicker? Which editing mode you use (form editing of not)? You wrote "date field is not displayed when I write the date field in grid". Do you have problem with **saving** of data?

Comment: @user2940331: If you would use the word "urgent" one more time I'll stop writing answers on your questions. I and other people who try to help you have *his own job*. We try to help you by spending owner private time. It's at least impolitely to hurry up us.

Comment: ohh i am sorry for that

Comment: @user2940331: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. You wrote: "it displayed the date format". Do you mean that the date will be displayed correctly in the column `joinedate`? You wrote "when i click the label not displayed the calender". Which "label" you click? Which "calender" you mean? **Which editing mode you use?**. *The code which you posted don't contains any editing.* Do you called `navGrid` and you use form editing by selection some row of the grid and clicking Edit button of navigation toolbar? How you edit the grid?

Comment: i am using jqgrid's .in the grid when click add icon one dialogue box ill display ..in that dialogue box i gave those fields ..joinedate field not displayed dateformat it's displayed label yy-mm-dd ,bt not showing calender

Comment: @user2940331: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DatePicker3.htm). It uses the code which you posted and I see no problem.

Comment: ya i know the demo ,it's working in single grid.in my project i used 5 grids and calling them through jsp pages....,so i think the problem is all css and js files are import 5 times on one jsp page through ajax call ... please can u tell me the solution ...thanks in adavance

Comment: @user2940331: You should load every CSS and every JS **once**. Nevertheless you asked a question with some problem description and some code which you included. Now you wrote that if you use the code which you posed there is no problem and the problem exist if you loads some JS files and some CSS files in the way which you not posted and if you use additionally another grids which you don't posted too. And you expect that somebody still solve your problem?

Comment: @user2940331: OK, if you use **multiple** grids you can make for example the following error: you can used **the same** `name` in `colModel` for different grids. It's restriction of form editing which you use. Can you verify that no  other grid have the column having `name:'joinedate'`?